# Grab a text from label and put it in array

Tags: javascript, html

How can I grab a text that user enters in label and add it to Array by clicking a button?
Here is my code that doesn't work:

```js
let dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
let labela = document.querySelector("#labela");
let forma = document.querySelector("#forma");
let tekst = document.querySelector("#tekst");
let niz = ["jedan", "dva", "tri"];

dugme.addEventListener("click", function() {
  niz.push(labela);
  document.getElementById("tekst").innerHTML = niz;
})
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="forma">
  <button id="dugme" type="button">+</button>
  <label id="labela"><input name="text" /></label>
  </form>
  <p id="tekst"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get input value for this. Check the below code for this:

```js
let dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
let labela = document.querySelector("#labela");
let labelaInupt = document.querySelector("#labela input");
let forma = document.querySelector("#forma");
let tekst = document.querySelector("#tekst");
let niz = ["jedan", "dva", "tri"];

dugme.addEventListener("click", function() {
  niz.push(labelaInupt.value);
  document.getElementById("tekst").innerHTML = niz;
})
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="forma">
  <button id="dugme" type="button">+</button>
  <label id="labela"><input name="text" /></label>
  </form>
  <p id="tekst"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html and js should look like this. So the main problem was you tried to get input value from `<label>` not from the `<input>` element itself.

```js
let dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
let labela = document.querySelector("#labela");
let forma = document.querySelector("#forma");
let tekst = document.querySelector("#tekst");
let input = document.querySelector("#text");
let niz = ["jedan", "dva", "tri"];

dugme.addEventListener("click", function() {
  niz.push(input.value);
  document.getElementById("tekst").innerHTML = niz;
})
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="forma">
  <button id="dugme" type="button">+</button>
  <label id="labela"><input id="text" name="text" /></label>
  </form>
  <p id="tekst"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `id` attribute at `input` component instead of setting `id` to `label`. Setting `id` to `label` is meaningless.

```js
let dugme = document.querySelector("#dugme");
let text = document.querySelector("#text");
let forma = document.querySelector("#forma");
let tekst = document.querySelector("#tekst");
let niz = ["jedan", "dva", "tri"];

dugme.addEventListener("click", function() {
  niz.push(text.value);
  document.getElementById("tekst").innerHTML = niz;
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <form id="forma">
  <button id="dugme" type="button">+</button>
  <label><input id="text" name="text" /></label>
  </form>
  <p id="tekst"></p>
</body>
```